# CURL import character encoding problem

Tags: php, encoding, curl

I'm using CURL to import some code. However, in french, all the characters come out funny. For example: BonjourÂ ...

I don't have access to change anything on the imported code. Is there anything I can do my side to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Your situation is unclear. Where does PHP come in? Is the content you're downloading PHP code? What are you using to view the text afterwards? It's almost certainly just a case of handling the downloaded data in the appropriate encoding. However, you'll need to know what encoding that is (look at the HTTP headers for a possible hint, although it may not have been set correctly) and how to *use* the right encoding. We can't help you on the latter point until we know what you're doing with the data after fetching it.

Comment: "Your situation is unclear. Where does PHP come in? Is the content you're downloading PHP code? What are you using to view the text afterwards?" -from Jon Skeet's answer below

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like Jon Skeet pointed it's difficult to understand your situation, however if you have access only to final text, you can try to use **iconv** for changing text encoding.

I.e.

```
$text = iconv("Windows-1252","UTF-8",$text);
```

I've had similar issue time ago (with Italian language and special chars) and I've solved it in this way.

Try different combination (UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, Windows-1252).

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem. I tried to loop through all combinations of input and output charsets. Nothing helped! :(

However I was able to access the code that actually fetched the data and this is where the culprit lied. Data was fetched via cURL. Adding

```
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,true);
```

fixed it.

A handy set of code to try out all possible combinations of a list of charsets:

```
$charsets = array(  
        "UTF-8", 
        "ASCII", 
        "Windows-1252", 
        "ISO-8859-15", 
        "ISO-8859-1", 
        "ISO-8859-6", 
        "CP1256"
        ); 

foreach ($charsets as $ch1) { 
    foreach ($charsets as $ch2){ 
        echo "<h1>Combination $ch1 to $ch2 produces: </h1>".iconv($ch1, $ch2, $text_2_convert); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP seems to use UTF-8 by default, so I found the following works

$text = iconv("UTF-8","Windows-1252",$text);

Answer (score 3):

You could replace your

```
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

by

```
$data = utf8_decode(curl_exec($ch));
```

I had this same issue and it worked well for me.

Comment: IMPORTANT: when converting UTF8 data that contains the EURO sign DON'T USE utf_decode function.

utf_decode converts the data into ISO-8859-1 charset. But ISO-8859-1 charset does not contain the EURO sign, therefor the EURO sign will be converted into a question mark character '?'

In order to convert properly UTF8 data with EURO sign you must use:

iconv("UTF-8", "CP1252", $data)

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently suffering a similar problem, i'm trying to write a simple html `<title>` importer cia cURL. So i'm going to give an idea of what i've done until now:

1. Retrieve the HTML via cURL
2. Check if there's any hint of encoding on the response headers via `curl_getinfo()` and match it via regex
3. Parse the HTML for the purpose of looking at the *content-type* meta and the `<title>` tag (yes, [i know the consequences](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/))
4. Compare both content-type, header and meta and choose the meta one if it's different, because we know noone cares about their httpd configuration and there are a lot of dirt workarounds using it
5. `iconv()` the string
6. Whish everyday that when someone does not follow the standards `$DEITY` punishes him/her until the end of the days, because it would save me the meta parsing