# php text encoding when GETting a webpage and then POSTing contents

Tags: php, http, character-encoding, libcurl

I'm trying to GET a webpage parse a part of it and then POST it as a value. The problem is: when there is a character as ó, I retrieve Ã³, and thus when posting it, the urlencode translation converts those characters to something completely different, which doesn't work.

More precisely, Ã³ is produced when an ó in utf-8 is interpreted as it was in ISO-9959-1, or at least that's what my browser does, if I set to view the page in utf-8 then I see ó, if I set the browser to view the page in ISO-9959-1 then I see Ã³, other encodings produce different symbols.

I tried to convert the results of the page, and also that specific string to utf-8, I did also try to set the headers to accept only utf-8, but that is not working either. I'm quite certain that is the problem but I'm running out of ideas. I changed the configuration in php.ini but maybe I did not restart yet, basically this is like shooting in the dark, and some help would be greatly appreciated.

If this helps: The specific code is here: https://github.com/trylks/golem/blob/master/php/copperGolem.php

The method is "form", when obtaining one of the parameter values from a previously obtained page with GET.

Thank you.

PD solved: I've been working on this for the last few hours, I can't tell if I changed many other things that are necessary. In any case, the last change that made it work was changing line 60 to be this: `$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($p, 'html-entities', mb_detect_encoding($p)));` That made it. The problem is not libcurl but DomDocument, as explained here: [PHP DomDocument failing to handle utf-8 characters (☆)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309194/php-domdocument-failing-to-handle-utf-8-characters)

Comment: Does this help? [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649480/curl-import-character-encoding-problem

Comment: @fyrye How does recursion help here?

Comment: @deceze updated to proper URL, odd browser copied wrong link >>

Comment: You said you tried to convert the page and the specific string to UTF-8 and force UTF-8 encoding via headers. Can you show how you did this?

Comment: headers are in line 20, and the conversion in line. I've tried to use `mb_convert_encoding` with the retrieved page and also with the parameters before `urlencode`. I think I tried with utf-8 and ISO-9959-1 but I'm going to double check before trying to install something additional like `iconv`.

Comment: * and the conversion in line 38 and 59, I'm still trying to figure out what's wrong, so I've used that in some other places, none of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `DomDocument`, it doesn't properly handle utf-8. Converting to html-entities is the safest option and it works like magic when outputting these characters back with echo (even using cli) or urlencoding these characters. Basically `DomDocument` doesn't accept utf-8 but it outputs utf-8, or so it seems. So it's a weird conversion that has to be made, so that DomDocument undoes it and everything is back to normal again.

To do this, and being `$dom` a DomDocument it's enough to do this on every call to `$dom->loadHTML($p)`:

`$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($p, 'html-entities', mb_detect_encoding($p)));`

This is explained better in this other question: [PHP DomDocument failing to handle utf-8 characters (☆)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309194/php-domdocument-failing-to-handle-utf-8-characters)