# How to save special characters in parse.com with the REST API

Tags: parse-platform

Does anyone know how we are supposed to call the REST API to store special characters? I have tried the following methods:

- No special handling at all. I noticed Parse can handle special characters such as #@$ etc. so I figured I will give this a shot. This ends up with no luck. sample curl query is:

`curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: appId" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: apikey" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json;" \
  -d '{"testString":"é"}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/TestObject`

This returns "{"code":107,"error":"The object contained an invalid utf8 string"}" which is sort of expected.

- Then I thought I would add the charset header in the post call, i.e.

`curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: appId" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: apikey" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
  -d '{"testString":"é"}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/TestObject`

This returns same result as the first attempt.

- Okay, then I tried manually encode it to UTF-8, i.e.

`curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: appId" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: apikey" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
  -d '{"testString":"%C3%A9"}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/TestObject`

Now this does create the row, however, the value is literally %C3%A9 as opposed to é. I tried taking out the charset value in the header which didn't seem to help either.

- I noticed everything worked perfect via the data browser. So I monitor the js query to see what db is sending out. It turned out the browser is sending Ã© for é. Then I proceed to change my curl and, tada, I got it, i.e.

`curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: appId" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: apikey" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
  -d '{"testString":"Ã©"}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/TestObject`

Finally gave me what I wanted which is value é.

Now I am puzzled, what kind of encoding converts é into Ã©? I got all sorts of other special foreign characters I need to handle too and I need to find a way to reliably encode them into the expected format...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My next question would be what kind of encoding library I should use to encode é into Ã©...

Comment: I don't understand it well enough to provide you a solution, but for a description of the problem, look at this entry: U+00E9 é Ã© %C3 %A9 in this Web page: http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html

Comment: Have a look at this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649480/curl-import-character-encoding-problem.  My *guess* is that your terminal's character encoding is either ISO-8859-1, Windows-1252 and Parse.com expects UTF8.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this in Terminal on OSX, without problems:

`curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: appID" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: restKey" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json;" \
  -d '{"testString":"é"}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/TestObject`

[image]

The character encoding in the terminal was set to UTF-8. However, when changed to ISO-8859-1, I got the same error as you:

```
{"code":107,"error":"invalid utf-8 string was provided"}
```

So @ahoffer is probably right that you don't have utf-8 set as your terminal's character encoding.